# Newtons Law of Cooling (Integration)

Tags: integration

The question is : An apple crumble is taken out of the oven at 7:30pm.

At that time, its temperature is 100 degrees Celsius.

At 7:40pm, ten minutes later, the temperature of the apple is 80 degrees Celsius.

At 7:50pm, after another ten minutes, the temperature of the apple is 65 degrees Celsius.

Calculate the temperature of the room.

---

What I have done:

$\frac{dT}{dt} = k (T-100)$

$T = Ae^{kt}+ 100$

At $t = 10 , T = 80$

$80 = Ae^{10k} + 100$

$-20/e^{10k} = A$

At $t = 20 , T = 65$

$65 = -20/e^{10k}*e^{20k} + 100$

$-35e^{10k} = -20e^{20k}$

$1.75 = e^{20k}/e^{10k}$

$1.75 = e^{10k}$

$(\ln(1.75))/10 = k$

Therefore subbing it back into $A , A = -80/7$

$T = -80/7e^((ln(1.75))/10t) + 100$

Therefore at $t = 0 , T = 88.7$ degrees Celsius , the answer states $20$ degrees

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newton's law of cooling write (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_cooling))
$$T(t)=T_{room}+(T(0)-T_{room})\,e ^{-r\,t}$$ So, using $t$ in minutes and $7:30$ being the reference time, what you are given is (using $T(0)=100$ as given)

$$80=T_{room}+(100-T_{room})\,e ^{-10r}$$
$$65=T_{room}+(100-T_{room})\,e ^{-20r}$$ So, we have two equations and two unknowns ($T_{room}$ and $r$). But what you can notice is that $e ^{-20r}=(e ^{-10r})^2$ (I bet that this is the trick in the problem). So, from the first equation $$e ^{-10r}=\frac{80-T_{room}}{100-T_{room}}$$ and from the second equation   $$e ^{-20r}=\frac{65-T_{room}}{100-T_{room}}$$ So, using what was noticed $$\frac{65-T_{room}}{100-T_{room}}=\left(\frac{80-T_{room}}{100-T_{room}}\right)^2$$ that is to say $$(65-T_{room})(100-T_{room})=(80-T_{room})^2$$ Just expand an simplify to get $T_{room}$.

What is interesting to notice here is that we do not care about $r$ because the conditions were given at $t_0$, $t_0+10$, $t_0+2\times 10$. The problem would have been quite different if the $65$ degrees had been reached at $7:41$; in such a case, it would have been required to solve for $r$ (this would have been much more difficult).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use Kelvins, not Celcius.

Comment: It is not required since only temperature differences are used.

Comment: Have you tried using $T_{\text{new}} = T_{\text{old}} + 273.15$?